# Vue.js project could not deploy to Azure with GitHub Actions

Tags: azure, vue.js, vuejs2, github-actions, azure-static-web-app

I want to deploy Vue.js app to azure with GitHub Actions. The Azure generated workflow file to GitHub. But I got this error:

> Failed to find a default file in the app artifacts folder (dist). Valid default files: index.html,Index.html.

My workflow configuration:

```yaml
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - test
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - test

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: true
          lfs: false
      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_AMBITIOUS_ROCK_03380B103 }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # Used for Github integrations (i.e. PR comments)
          action: "upload"
          ###### Repository/Build Configurations - These values can be configured to match your app requirements. ######
          # For more information regarding Static Web App workflow configurations, please visit: https://aka.ms/swaworkflowconfig
          app_location: "/" # App source code path
          api_location: "" # Api source code path - optional
          output_location: "dist" # Built app content directory - optional
          ###### End of Repository/Build Configurations ######
```

Comment: Have you verified that the `index.html` file exists or not?

Comment: I've index.html in root directory. Not in dist directory.

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating one **`VueJs app`** and deployed it to Azure static Web app successfully, Refer below:-

My **`VueJs app`** **[Github repository](https://github.com/sid24desai/Vueapp2)**:-

I created **`VueJs app`** with the commands [**here**](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html).

***Github YAML code:-***

```yaml
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: true
          lfs: false
      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_GRAY_MOSS_03D025A03 }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} 
          action: "upload"
          app_location: "/" 
          api_location: "" 
          output_location: "dist" 

  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_GRAY_MOSS_03D025A03 }}
          action: "close"
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

Comment: @SiddeshDesai thank you for your support. Your project deployed as well. But i'm working with Vue 2. Is there any possible deployment for Vue 2 ?

Comment: I am using Vue 2 only for the deployment

Comment: The only difference, my index.html placed in root folder, but your indext.html place in public folder.

Comment: Can you try adding your index.html in a public folder? and check the deployment?

Comment: It is still not working @SiddeshDesai